# Virtual Environment for each tools to avoid dependency conflicts?

Tags: docker, python-venv

I was wondering If any one could help me to understand the difference of python virtual environment and docker container.

So I would like to have environment for each tools isolating from each other to avoid dependency conflict for example: use of different version of same dependency causing error in one of the tool because one tool need older version and other one requires newer version.

I’m tested out python venv but not sure if it’s the right one I should use for the issue I just explained or docker is something I should be using for my situation?.

Comment: For tools that are pip-installable (i.e. tools that are on _PyPI_) the current community practice is to use [_pipx_](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/). It cleanly isolates each tool/app in its own virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly for day-to-day development, prefer a virtual environment if it's practical.

| Virtual environment | Docker |
| --- | --- |
| Works with native tools; can just run `python myscript.py` | Requires Docker-specific setup |
| Every IDE and editor works fine with it | Requires Docker-specific IDE support |
| Can just `open()` data files with no special setup | Can't access data files without Docker-specific mount setup |
| Immediately re-run code after editing it | Re `docker build` image or use Docker-specific mount setup |
| Uses Python installation from host | Use any single specific version of Python |
| Isolated Python library tree | Isolated Python library tree |
| Uses host version of C library dependencies | Isolated C library dependencies |

A virtual environment acts like a normal Python installation in an alternate path.  You don't need to do special things to make your local code or data files available; you can just run your script directly or via your IDE.  The one downside is that you're limited to what your host OS's package manager makes available for Python versions and C library dependencies.

A Docker container contains the filesystem of a complete OS, including a completely isolated Python installation.  It can be a good match if you need a very specific version of Python or if you need host OS dependencies that are tricky to install.  It can also be a good match if you're looking for a production-oriented deployment setup that doesn't specifically depend on installing things on to the target system.  But, Docker by design makes it hard to access your host files; it is not a great match for a live development environment or especially for one-off scripts that read and write host files.

The other consideration here is, if you use the standard Python packaging tools, it's straightforward to run your program in a virtual environment, and converting that to a Docker image is almost boilerplate.  Starting from Docker can make it tricky to go back the other way, and I see some setups around SO that can only be run via Docker; if they were restructured to use a standard `setup.cfg`/`requirements.txt` installation setup they would not require Docker but could still be used with it.